# document clustering using word2vec

Tags: k-means, word2vec, word-embedding

I am doing document clustering using Word2vec (genism library)

The following steps that I am doing,

1. Cleaning and tokenizing data, let's say I have 50000 data
2. Generating vector representations of the documents using the word2vec model. Here, for each word, having a word embedding vector. (i.e. word2vec model size 300)
3. Then getting word embedding vector for each document by Mean of Word Embeddings (MOWE), that's mean by adding all embedding vector for each word in a document by dividing total word number in that document. (dimension of the embedding vector of entire corpus: 50000X300)
4. Next be measuring cosine similarity matrix on the entire dataset(50000X300), get cosine similarity matrix( dimension 50000X50000)
5. In the final step, I am sending this cosine similarity matrix to kmeans algorithm. Here, I am using scipy library for kmeans algorithm.

I have confusion in step 4.

My question is, do I need to calculate cosine similarity matrix for kmeans algorithm?
Or Instead of cosine similarity can I fed embedding vector for the entire dataset(50000X300) to kmeans algorithm?

Which one should I follow and why?

Comment: Which specific KMeans code/library are you using? Have you tried something and hit an error or unsatisfactory result? (It looks to me like the `scikit-learn` `KMeans` class wants the samples, not the matrix of similarities, and thus will do its own pairwise similarity calculations - but maybe you're using something else. And also beware: if either your code, or your library, calculates a full 50,000x50,000 matrix, even if it only have 4-byte `np.float32` numbers, it will still require 10GB of RAM to hold in memory.)

Comment: I am using scipy kmeans algorithm.

Comment: When I look at the docs at <https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans.html>, I don't see any indication that it needs a precalculated pairwise distances array. If you've tried something & hit problems, you may want to either ask a new question, or update this question, with more excerpts from your actual code & details of any errors/unsatisfying-results.

Comment: Actually, I am not getting any error with the cosine similarity for kmeans. To calculate cosine similarity is and pass to it means the algorithm is not memory efficient. However, I am just not sure, will it be ok if I pass the word embedding vector to kmeans algorithm

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: I didn't run it with word embedding yet.